# useEffect hook for saving to localStorage when user closes the browser tab

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks

I'm trying to save a `key:value` to `localStorage` using the "cleanup return" of `useEffect()` hook.

This is my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const onbeforeunloadFn = () => {
      localStorage.setItem('color', 'red')
    }

    window.addEventListener('onbeforeunload', onbeforeunloadFn);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload', onbeforeunloadFn);
    }
  }, [])
```

I even tried in `onbeforeunloadFn handler` to `prevent` default behavior and return a `string` but it is also not working. 
Following the [onbeforeunload doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Can anyone explain me why or how can I make this code so it works **just** when the user close the `browser tab`?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using addEventListener() remove “on” from the event string. It would just be addEventListener(“beforeunload”)

Comment: This is not a proper use case for `useEffect` hook. `useEffect` is though to hook into the mounting - dismounting operations, not to perform this kind of operation. You should put the saving logic outside from React and use some kind of storage (like a global variable) to remember data to store at browser tab close. React Hooks have nothing to do here

Comment: @Keilath no using an effect is actually exactly what is needed here, because he wants to set an event listener on `window` only once when the app mounts. This is a textbook use case for it. So textbook that something similar appears as an example in the official React docs, even. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky is correct I think. You're using the wrong string value for the event listener. Should just be `beforeunload`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @AlexanderStaroselsky mentioned, I think you just slightly misspelled the event name.

```
useEffect(() => {

    const onbeforeunloadFn = () => {
      localStorage.setItem('color', 'red')
    }

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onbeforeunloadFn);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onbeforeunloadFn);
    }
  }, [])
```

Interestingly, the [English language version of the doc you referred to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) has a slightly different example that would have probably helped you identify the error:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) { ... });
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) { ... };
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jered Just a quick question. What happen if I just want this to run when the user closes the tab but not when the component mounts?

Comment: @Peter I'm not sure what you mean. useEffect will run once when the component mounts, adding the window event listener. When the window closes, the callback `onbeforeunloadFn` will run. `onbeforeunloadFn` won't run when the component first mounts.